# Manipulating ANT Tasks (set properties) during runtime

Tags: java, ant

I'm using ant tasks in my project to do a lot of things like creating directories, deleting files and so on. In this case I get a list of branches from my SVN-server, which works perfectly. This all happens during the runtime of my program, firing the tasks from out the java-code.

My question is: Is it possible to manipulate the ant-file (tasks.xml)? The user should enter username/password combination and when firing the task, these credentials should be used in my ant-task instead of the properties.

Ant-file:

```
<target name="getBranchList">
    <exec executable="c:/svnclient/svn.exe" 
            output="c:/test/output/versionsonsvn.log">
        <arg value="ls" />
        <arg value="--username" />
        <arg value="${svn.user}" />
        <arg value="--password" />
        <arg value="${svn.password}" />
        <arg value="--non-interactive" />
        <arg value="--trust-server-cert" />
        <arg value="${svn.server}" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

How I use it in Java:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.*;

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
    v.add("getBranchList");
    v.add("someOtherTask");
    fireAntTasks("c:/test/tasks.xml", v); }

private void fireAntTasks(String fileName, Vector<String> v) {
    File taskFile = new File(fileName);
    if (buildFile.exists()) {
        Project p = new Project();
        p.setUserProperty("ant.file", buildFile.getAbsolutePath());
        p.init();
        ProjectHelper helper = ProjectHelper.getProjectHelper();
        p.addReference("ant.projectHelper", helper);
        helper.parse(p, buildFile);
        p.executeTargets(v);

    } else {
        System.out.println("File not found!");
    }
}
```

The only solution I could imagine is to manipulate the file directly (setting the properties in "tasks.xml" during runtime). But maybe there is a better way to get this working...

Greetings

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand you but I'm guessing your trying to get user input to replace some properties.

You can either use the [Input Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/input.html) which will prompt the user of which you can store into a variable.

Or you can load a properties file that the user edit before executing ant through the [property task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html).

Comment: Thats exactly what I was searching for! I request the credentials (SVN, database, Windows) as the program starts, later the program should insert it (using the input-task, if this works) when it's needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve something like this with the [loadproperties task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadproperties.html) and a properties file:

```
<loadproperties srcFile="build.properties"/>
```

Every user will have to create a `build.properties` in the build directory and put the values in it like this:

```
svn.user = user
svn.password = password
```

You could also make it, so that this files resides in the home directory:

```
<loadproperties srcFile="${user.home}/build.properties"/>
```

This way the file will be protected a little bit more.